Can I change an SD card volume serial number manually, without formatting?
My laptop runs on stable Arch Linux. My tablet is running Android 14.
I have apps that are linked to a dead card that are very difficult to change the link to. Now I do know you can randomly get a new volume serial number. The thing is, can you deliberately change an SD card volume serial number=1234-abcd to volume serial number=0987-mnbv?
The card is formatted to exFAT. Plugged in a slot but listed as external SD. Already has data on it that I do not want to lose.
Edit: exfatlabel works. Note:To change volume serial number must use 0x12345678 instead of 1234-5678. Follow the linked notes.

I assume you are talking about the "volume serial number" - possible duplicate of Can I rename the external storage mount point on Android10 with root access

Thanks for getting me on the right track. Haven't tried it yet as still backing up info on new card. For Linux exfatlabel link

Feel free to add an answer here or on the linked question, describing exfatlabel program.

This question is similar to: Can I rename the external storage mount point on Android10 with root access. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
